# VS2012 Using a standard ASP.NET Web User Control in a SharePoint Visual Web Part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012

All,

I have created an empty SharePoint Project in VS2012.1.  I have added a Visual Web Part to it which I can add various Standard controls to and deploy to my SharePoint site on my local machine fine.

What I want to do is to create a custom ASP.NET Control in my SharePoint Project.  However there is no option in VS2012 to add a new ASP.NET Web User Control to my SharePoint project.  Is this possible to do?

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: The only option i have seen is the User Control(Farm Solution Only) option. Have you tried creating the control in a seperate project and referencing it in?

Comment: I thought about doing that.  I think you need to sign and deploy the project to the GAC.  I have just come across the User Control (Farm Solution Only) and I think I might just stick with that.  Just wondered why you can't have standard ASP.NET User Controls in a SharePoint project

Comment: you will need to sign them for sure but you can always add a signing key from another project!